# .NET Core UserControl missing from toolbox

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, user-controls

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 Windows Forms from Visual Studio 2019 16.7.0 Preview 2.0. I created a UserControl as part of the same project that contains the forms I want to add the control to. From experience with Framework it should appear in the toolbox when I rebuild the solution but it's not there. I sometimes had that issue with Framework and fixed it by selecting Choose items>Browse and choosing the app executable, but doing so with my .NET Core app simply says the file is not valid. The same appens selecting any DLL in the solution folder. Are there any other way I could add the control to the form? I tried editing the designer manually based on existing code for the other controls, but all references to the new control were deleted when building.

Comment: The solution was originally created in .NET Framework with existing usercontrols that proprely appeared in the toolbox and added to some forms. I ported it to .NET Core by copying all the code and although the existing usercontrols don't appear in the toolbox either, the ones already placed in some forms work as expected.

Comment: Be sure the following is set to true Check this setting:

Tools > Options > Windows Forms Designer > General : AutoToolboxPopulate

It should be set to True for this to work. Also be sure you have the designer window open too. Does any of that help?

Comment: AutoToolboxPopulate is True

Comment: You need to right click on the toolbox, select "Choose Items.." and browse to the dll containing the control. Does that work? If it doesn't is it possible the control was made for .net framework and not .net core?

Comment: Not sure under .net Core as it's still a preview and I haven't used it, but under WIndows Forms until you compile the control it doesn't appears on the toolbar. Have you compiled your project after the migration?

Comment: .NET Core has no dedicated dlls for user controls

Comment: any solution?? I've the same problem?